# How to implement the key for "enter" in a dictionary?

Tags: javascript

I've written a simple substitution cipher using a dictionary for the keys/values containing letters, numbers, and some symbols. I could not, however, find a way to implement a key/value for "enter" (newline). Is there a way I could make it work as a dictionary value or would it require me to re-write the code in a different way?

Also, in a completely different question, is it possible to create a dictionary in JS using regex instead of inserting a unique key-value for each entry? What would that look like?

Here's how I've done it:

```
//Substitution function
  let caseString = message.value.toUpperCase().split("");
  let newString = [];
  for (let unit of caseString) {
    for (let letter in alphabet) {
      if (unit === alphabet[letter]) {
        newString.push(alphabet[unit]);
      }
    }
  }
  cipher.value = newString.join("");
```

```
//Dictionary object holding the alphabet keys & values
const alphabet = {
  A: "Z",
  B: "Y",
  C: "X",
  D: "W",
  E: "V",
  F: "U",
  G: "T",
  H: "S",
  I: "R",
  J: "Q",
  K: "P",
  L: "O",
  M: "N",
  N: "M",
  O: "L",
  P: "K",
  Q: "J",
  R: "I",
  S: "H",
  T: "G",
  U: "F",
  V: "E",
  W: "D",
  X: "C",
  Y: "B",
  Z: "A",
  " ": " ",
  "-": "-",
  _: "_",
  "!": "!",
  ":": ":",
  ";": ";",
  "'": "'",
  '"': '"',
  $: "$",
  "%": "%",
  "&": "&",
  "*": "*",
  "(": "(",
  ")": ")",
  "@": "@",
  1: "1",
  2: "2",
  3: "3",
  4: "4",
  5: "5",
  6: "6",
  7: "7",
  8: "8",
  9: "9",
  0: "0",
};
```

I'm aware it might be a silly approach to it, but I wanted to practice and see if I could actually make it work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use the [keyboard events key API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)?

Comment: Newline is typically "\n".

Comment: Would it not be easier using the Unicode value of the characters as the key instead of literal characters? It might also be easier for you to randomise it that way (easier to loop through the appropriate range of keys).

Comment: You shouldn't have to have the nested loops. The whole point of dictionaries/maps is being able to access their values in constant time. You _can_ access object properties like this: `let key = 'A'; alphabet[key]; // (would return 'Z')`.

Comment: I didn't use the API because I hadn't thought of it. Well, tbh I did think about mapping the keyboard keys, but since I was studying dictionaries I thought it would be wise to practice with that. And the \n worked, I had tried it before but must have made a typo. And it would probably be easier to do that, will do it for my next project. And that is most likely the best approach, I'll try to implement that next time!

Answer (score 1):

The newline character is represented with `"\n"` so you could add it to your dictonary like this:

```js
{
  "\n": "\n"
}
```

As for dictonaries with regex, you can try passing a replacement function to a string's `.replace()` funktion. For example, this would change out only letters:

```js
const input = "hello! 123"
const replace = {
  A: "f",
  B: "a",
  // ...
  h: "U",
  e: "T",
  l: "A",
  o: "k",
}
const result = input.replace(
  /[A-z]/g, 
  letter => replace[letter]
)
console.log(result) // <- "UTAAk! 123"
```

If you want to simplify your algorithm, check out the `charCodeAt()` and `fromCharCode()` functions.

Comment: Thanks! I see there was another comment suggesting that as well, and to no one's surprise but mine, it worked! I had tried that before, but I guess I must have made a typo.

Comment: Also, thank you for addressing the regex part of the question, I appreciate that!